# Google Script get values from UserForm Sheet to Data Sheet. even if I insert or delete row in UserForm

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a situation, in which I may insert or delete rows. so I could not specify the exact cell range

Please help with this code, What I am doing wrong (beginner), I have tried the below code.
I am trying to achieve this by **getnamedranges** (correct me if wrong)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NY_ckzEWxU7DCGro5tTqzpiOi6iG5PAQFxpZg0OKodY/edit?usp=sharing

```
function submitData() {
     
  var myGooglSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //declare a variable and set with active google sheet 
 
  var shUserForm= myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("UserForm"); //delcare a variable and set with the User Form worksheet
 
  var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Datasheet"); ////delcare a variable and set with the Datasheet worksheet


  //to create the instance of the user-interface environment to use the messagebox features

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  // Display a dialog box with a title, message, and "Yes" and "No" buttons. The user can also
  // close the dialog by clicking the close button in its title bar.
  var response = ui.alert("Submit", 'Do you want to submit the data?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
 
  // Checking the user response and proceed with clearing the form if user selects Yes
  if (response == ui.Button.NO) 
  {return;//exit from this function
  } 
 
  //Validating the entry. If validation is true then proceed with transferring the data to Datasheet sheet
  // if (validateEntry()==true)
 {
  
    var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1; //identify the next blank row
 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G4").getValue()); //Date
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("J4").getValue()); //UserForm Number
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C3").getValue()); //Student Name
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 4).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C6").getValue()); //ID
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("H8").getValue()); //Project Name
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G5").getValue()); //Batch Number 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 7).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("cellname1").getValue()); // Get cellname1
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(shUserForm.getNamedRanges("cellname2").getValue());//Get cellname2
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 9).setValue(shUserForm.getNamedRanges("cellname3").getValue());// Get cellname3
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 10).setValue(shUserForm.getNamedRanges("cellname4").getValue());// Get cellname4
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 11).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C9").getValue());// Summary
   
    // date function to update the current date and time as submittted on
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 12).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd h:mm'); //Submitted On
    
    //get the email address of the person running the script and update as Submitted By
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 13).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()); //Submitted By
    
    ui.alert(' "New Data Saved - Emp #' + shUserForm.getRange("C3").getValue() +' "');
```

[![sample1][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxCdT.png

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: thanks for your reply :)
I have attached the sample image. Please refer. thank you so much

Comment: Thank you for providing sample images. Now, I displayed them by editing your question. When I saw your 2 images, I cannot understand which is the sample input situation and sample output situations. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: Pls share a spreadsheet. People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: @MikeSteelson  as advised I have given a link to my google sheet with the script.  waiting for the solution. Thank you

Comment: @Tanaike - by mistake, I have attached two same images. thanks for pointing it out. I have given a link to google sheet with the script for better and easy execution. Hoping for the solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have a difference bteween 2 names : `TotalPresentt` vs `TotalPresent` !

You can use directly `shUserForm.getRange("TotalPresentt").getValue()`

Try this

```
// Function to submit the data to DataSheet sheet
function submitData() {

  var myGooglSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //declare a variable and set with active google sheet 
  var shUserForm = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("UserForm"); //delcare a variable and set with the User Form worksheet
  var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("DataSheet"); ////delcare a variable and set with the DataSheet worksheet

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert("Submit", 'Do you want to submit the data?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (response == ui.Button.NO) {
    return;
  }

  var blankRow = datasheet.getLastRow() + 1; //identify the next blank row

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C3").getValue()); //Date
  datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C4").getValue()); //UserForm Number
  datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C5").getValue()); //Student Name
  datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 4).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C6").getValue()); //ID
  datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C7").getValue()); //Project
  datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C8").getValue()); //Group Name
  datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("TotalPresentt").getValue());// TotalPresent
  datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("SoundRoomDay").getValue());// SoundRoomDAy
  datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 9).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("GroupDay").getValue());// GroupDay
  datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 10).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("TotalDays").getValue());// TotalDays

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 12).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd h:mm'); //Submitted On
  datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 13).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()); //Submitted By

  ui.alert(' "New Data Saved - StudentID #' + shUserForm.getRange("C5").getValue() + ' "');

}
```

Comment: further, I am asking for another help instead of posting data to another sheet and i need to post it to another workbook using id
```
var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("DataSheet"); ////delcare a variable and set with the DataSheet worksheet
```

Comment: Try `var datasheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id of the target spreadsheet').getSheetByName("DataSheet")`

Comment: @HummingBird, let's try and focus on a single question in a post. If you have further questions unrelated to the main issue, then feel free to post it as another question.